# ubuntu apt - why are the respositories accessed over HTTP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, http, packages, apt

So I was just updating my Ubuntu 18.04 system as usual, when I noticed that the apt repositories are being accessed via HTTP. A quick internet search confirmed that this is standard (at least with ubuntu), but didn't yield an answer to why. Now I know that apt performs signature / sanity checks of the packages, but still, why isn't HTTPS used?

**Edit 2019-01-24:** In light of the recent RCE exploit because of the HTTP communication, I want to point out to some current links I found regarding this topic.

https://whydoesaptnotusehttps.com/ -> A single purpose website only for explaning why HTTP is sufficient.

https://justi.cz/security/2019/01/22/apt-rce.html -> How to exploit the HTTP connection to execute arbitrary code on the target host (and also how to protect yourself against such an attack).

https://usn.ubuntu.com/3863-1/ -> Ubuntu security notice

https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/2019/msg00010.html -> Debian security advisory.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu developers at Canonical.

Comment: Well...thank you. I tagged this question with 'apt' and 'ubuntu', why wouldn't it be okay to ask here?

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Yes, you might be correct. However, since not only Ubuntu uses apt, it might be wrong there as well. I just checked the default Debian sources.list which also uses simple HTTP.
Edit: However then my tags and question title might be misleading.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the time the files are downloaded from a mirror and not from the ubuntu servers, so even if the ubuntu site uses HTTPS, you are going to be downloading files from sites like `http://ubuntu.unc.edu.ar/ubuntu/`or `http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/`.

To overcome this problem, the files downloaded by APT have a signature that allows that it can be verified against the public keys stored on your computer as being signed by Ubuntu and only Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand that public key signatures protect the integrity and authenticity of data. However wouldn't it be desirable to encrypt the data as well so that an adversary might not know what software and what versions thereof are used? I can imagine a - yes maybe complex - attack where an attacker uses the information which software version is used in an attack.

Comment: @M.Geiger That is indeed a concern of some users, including myself. IMO there is no good reason to use plain HTTP for package repositories these days, and at least one very good reason to use HTTPS, as you pointed out.

Comment: @l0b0 Ok, so I'm not the only one. I also found the package [apt-transport-https](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-transport-https), which looks like it should do the job. I already had this installed. Unfortunately, when I switch every http to https in my Ubuntu sources.list, updating fails with `Could not connect to de.archive.ubuntu.com:443 (141.30.62.25). - connect (111: Connection refused)`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is because is a layer not necessary for the purpose!
I mean https is needed to encrypt the data over the network to avoid to send sensitive data in clear text (never authenticate your self in http protocol).
So have no traffic to protect there, mostly of the code is opensource and can be downloaded and redistribuite. What is need to be protected is the binary package by him self, but for this all the package in the repository are digital signed, and if the public key is not installed on your package manager will notify you that the software you begin to install is came from a not trusted place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate the hint that most of linux software is open source, so this might be a good reason, why it doesn't have to be encrypted for confidentiality.